# npm ERR! code ELOOP while trying download

Tags: angular

I want to integrate with google login, I tried the command: `npm install --save angularx-social-login` but it gives the error:

```
D:\proj>npm install --save angularx-social-login
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\proj\node_modules\angularx-social-login\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4067
npm ERR! ELOOP: too many symbolic links encountered, open 'D:\proj\node_modules\angularx-social-login\package.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-11T13_29_41_934Z-debug.log
```

I am using angular 9

Comment: Well, there were too many symbolic links to follow when opening the file. Isn't that what the error message told you about? Try to trace system calls (IDK what is used on Windows for that).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to run `npm install --save react-router-dom` on an old React project. I ended up upgrading the versions in "package.json" file to be the latest and deleted "node_modules". After running `npm install` to install latest versions, I was able run `npm install --save react-router-dom` to add the "react-router-dom" package, with no errors.